# Использование Claims или кэширование

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Нужно снизить нагрузку на БД. Чтобы пользователь мог нажать кнопку (оправить данные на сервер), например 1 раз в день. Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно писать в куки Claims, или свои какието данные в шифрованном виде.

Например объект сериализованный в JSON, который затем зашифровать с помощью ключа или соли.